# Why is my World Completion at 99% with 300/303 hearts?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I just finished World Completion and got my 2 Gifts of Exploration. However, the "Been There, Done That" achievement is at 99/100 and my World Completion percentage is at 99% with 300/303 Renown Hearts completed. What am I missing, here?

[image: World Completion 99%]

[image: Been There, Done That 99/100]

Comment: Uh, I'm guessing 3 renown hearts?

Comment: Found a related question on reddit: http://redd.it/2fy2uf. New hearts were added on Sept 9th. This technically should affect everyone's characters and move their world map completion from 100% to 99%.

Comment: It does affect the completion percentage, but once you have the title, it will stay! I am at 97% because of additions, but still have the title!

Comment: Conversely, if you didn't already have the title before the patch, then you cannot get it until you've done the extra hearts.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With the [September 2014 Feature Pack](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/September_2014_Feature_Pack), 3 new Renown Hearts were added (though, not mentioned in the patch notes). If you have previously completed the zones that the Renown Hearts were added to, then you will still be able to receive your Gifts of Exploration upon map completion. However, the full world map will still be technically incomplete.

You can find the new Renown Hearts in **Caledon Forest** and **Plains of Ashford**. The hearts are close to the entrances of their nearest city, meaning that the new Renown Hearts in Caledon Forest are near the entrance to The Grove and the new Renown Hearts in Plains of Ashford are near the entrance to Black Citadel. The hearts will not be visible on the map until you speak to the Scout near the entrance of the city you are coming from, even though you've already explored this area.

### Caledon Forest

[image: Caledon Forest's new Renown Heart]

- ❤ [Help Delilah keep the farmer's fields safe.](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Help_Delilah_keep_the_farmer%27s_fields_safe)

### Plains of Ashford

[image: Plains of Ashford's new Renown Hearts]

- ❤ [Help Tolona Ironrustler with her farm.](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Help_Tolona_Ironrustler)
- ❤ [Rid the training area of pests.](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Rid_the_training_area_of_pests)

Comment: Nice catch. When games do this they really should give the players a bit of a heads-up. Especially for people like me. NEED... 100%....

Comment: Great answer. You should really consider adding this information to the Guild Wars 2 official wiki as well: [Plains of Ashford](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Plains_of_Ashford) & [Caledon Forest](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Caledon_Forest)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that Renown hearts are invisible on the map. Once you discover them, then you can complete the tasks involved to complete the Renown Heart.

Seeing as you're missing 3, it looks like you need to do some more exploring.

From the [wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Renown_Heart):

> Hearts are invisible on the map until you discover them. You can discover them by talking to a nearby scout, or walking into its range.

Comment: The hearts are invisible until you discover them, but there is always a scout (binocular symbol) visible on the map near uncompleted hearts

Comment: You can also cross-reference your map with the maps on the wiki. That helped a bit more for me.